# how can i Save data to a value question to use It later in my code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, callback

i want to save the data to the question variable here is the code :

```
let question
async function genarater() {
    await questionModel.questionModel.findRandom({}, {
            constructor
        }, {
            limit: 3
        },
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let result;
let question = async function genarater() {
await questionModel.questionModel.findRandom(
    {},
    { constructor },
    { limit: 3 },
    function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
                result = data; 
            }
        },
    );
};
console.log(result)
```

I have successfully saved the result of the async operation into a variable named result and it happened in the `else` block of code.

Comment: I want to use what I get inside the else "data"  outside genarater function

Comment: oh I see. create a variable outside the `genarater` function and set the value to the variable inside the `generater` function and then you can use outside.

Comment: I did before but I get the result of undefined when i try to `log` it outside the `genarater`

Comment: I have updated the solution. it could only mean there is result from the `async` operation.

Comment: I see I did that before but still get `undefined `

Comment: The operation will return a result only in the callback region. Try this now.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `callback` and `async/await` together, and use `try/catch` with `async/await`.

if the `plugin` support `async/await` you can do like this

```
async function genarater() {
  try {
    let data = await questionModel.questionModel.findRandom(
      {},
      { constructor },
      { limit: 3 }
    );
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

for getting random data

```
let randomData = await genarater();
```